# Javascript: How to create new variable with different name inside loop depending on the index

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create new variables with different names each time a loop iteration completes but it doesn't seem to work. Here's the code I'm using

```
function Brick() {
    var b = $(this);
    b.content = '<div class="brick"></div>';
    b.width = 100/o.x; // 'o' is an object I created earlier
    b.height = 100/o.y;
}

for ( var i = 0; i < numberOfBricks; i++ ) {
    var brick[i] = new Brick();
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: by using var brick[i], you are losing all but the last Brick() instance.

Comment: `var b = $(this);` This line confuses me. Why are you converting a native object to Jquery? Or do you have any function with a name `$`?

Comment: Also `var brick[i] = new Brick();` This is not a valid syntax.

Comment: you cant create variable using code, but you can declare an empty array inside your loop and push value into this array, again you can create variables with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with bracket notation, something like this

```
function Brick() {
    var b = $(this);
    b.content = '<div class="brick"></div>';
    b.width = 100/o.x; // 'o' is an object I created earlier
    b.height = 100/o.y;
}

var bricks={}
for ( var i = 0; i < numberOfBricks; i++ ) {
    bricks['brick_'+i] = new Brick();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare an array outside of the loop, then push instances into the array:

```js
function Brick() {}

var brick = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfBricks; i++) {
  brick[i] = new Brick();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should declare the brick variable outside the loop.

```
var brick = new Array();
```

or

```
var brick = [];
```

Inside the loop you should only reference that variable.

```
brick[i] = new Brick();
```

Also, `var b = $(this)` is not necessary, you could simply:

```
function Brick() {
     this.content = '...';
     this.width = 100/o.x;
     this.height = 100/o.y;
}
```